# create bigrams for every line in a bilingual terms list

Tags: python

```
text = myfile
biterms = list of bilingual terms
bigrams = []
trans = biterms.split(' > ')
for it in trans[0].split(', '):
    for en in trans[1].split(', '):
        bigrams.append((it, en))
```

This code creates bigrams for all the lines in the file, but what I need here is bigrams for every line alone, i.e, for every item in the biterms list its bigrams.Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate over each line.

```
biterms = u'''Difensori dei diritti umani, libertà di espressione > Human rights defenders, freedom of expression
sgomberi forzati, violazioni dei diritti umani > forced evictions, human rights violations'''.splitlines()
bigrams = []
for line in biterms:
    l = []
    trans = line.split(' > ')
    left =  trans[0].split(', ')
    right = trans[1].split(', ')
    for i in left:
        for j in right:
            l.append((i, j))
    bigrams.append(l)        

for g in bigrams:
    print g
```

Comment: This gives me the bigrms for all the line, but I want the format: line:its bigrmas; line: its bigrams, etc.